# How to redirect to the same page with data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, current-page

I want to redirect to the same page with data array.

```
$this->load->view('view_name',$data);
```

like this how can I refresh the same page with data. please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flashdata` for that.

```
$data = array(
  'data1' => 'value',
  'data2' => 'value'
);

$this->session->set_flashdata('mydata',$data);
redirect('controller');
```

check data the data on your controller by.

```
var_dump($this->session->flashdata('mydata'));
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html